# Running CLI/terminal programs as entirely separate program (i.e not as an instance of Urxvt with -e toggle?)

Tags: command-line, icons, .desktop, openbox

I'm currently running Openbox as WM, with Urxvt as terminal emulator, and zsh as shell.

I use Mutt for emailing, Ranger for files, Cortex for redditing, Newsbeuter for RSSing. All of these programs are keybound to run from Urxvt with the -e toggle, here's an example from my /Openbox/rc.xml of how I start Ncmpcpp:

```
<keybind key="W-F5"><action name="Execute">
  <command>urxvt -name ncmpcpp -e ncmpcpp -h 192.168.x.x -p 1337
  </command>
 </action>
```

All the other programs are pretty much started the same way. I end up with something like this: [image]

I.e, all of these terminal programs end up under Urxvt. I would like to be able to have separate icons for all of the above programs, i also want them to be on their own when alt-tabbing.

I have tried making a ncmpcpp.desktop file which contains the following:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Ncmpcpp
GenericName=NCurses Music Player Client
Exec=ncmpcpp -h 192.168.1.x -p 1337
Terminal=true
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio;Player;ConsoleOnly;
Icon=/home/joel/ncmpccp.png
```

To no avail. Ncmpccp is still lumped together with Urxvt both in Plank and in the alt-tab menu. Ofcourse it is run from URxvt, but shouldn't it be possible to run it independently?

Appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Which dock app are you using?

Comment: I'm using Plank with the default theme.

Comment: I've also tried using Docky, same thing.